# Use of final in anonymous class

Tags: java, final, anonymous-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

```
private void printPrize(final int f,final int f1){  
        System.out.println("f  "+ f+" f1 "+ f1);  
        TT t= new TT(){  

            @Override  
            public int count() {  
               return calculateCount(f, f1);  
            }  

        };  
        t.getCount();  
    }
```

i force to mark f and f1 as final to access them in the anonymous class. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Comment: Doesn't anyone know how to use search engines anymore? This was in the top 3 search results on google. I would downvote this question, but I don't have the privileges for that yet. :D